# Query to find if a aggregate string contains certain numbers

Tags: sql, string, csv, google-bigquery

I am working on Big Query Standard SQL. I have a data table like shown below (using ; as separator):

```
id;operation
107327;-1,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,0,2,-1
108296;-1,6,2,-1,-1,-1
690481;0,-1,-1,-1,5
102643;5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,2,3,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
103171;0,5
789481;0,-1,5
```

I would like to take `id` that only contains operation `0,5` or `0,-1,5` so the result will show:

```
690481
103171
789481
```

Comment: Please share code snippets of what you have tried already to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 0 = (
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(operation)) op
  WHERE NOT op IN ('0', '-1', '5')
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data form your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 107327 id, '-1,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,0,2,-1' operation UNION ALL
  SELECT 108296, '-1,6,2,-1,-1,-1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 690481, '0,-1,-1,-1,5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 102643, '5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,2,3,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103171, '0,5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 789481, '0,-1,5' 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 0 = (
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(operation)) op
  WHERE NOT op IN ('0', '-1', '5')
)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This answer solves my problem precisely. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expression does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where regexp_contains(operation, '^0,(-1,)*5$');
```

If you want matches to rows that contain only 0, -1, or 5, you would use:

```
where regexp_contains(operation, '^((0|-1|5),)*(0|-1|5)$');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this case, I should ignore the order. The actual data not always started by 0 and ended by 5. It can be 5,0,-1 or -1,5,0 etc.

Comment: @August . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  All the examples have exactly these numbers in this order and that is what the question specifies.